# Arabic text messages in matlab

Tags: matlab, character-encoding, dialog, arabic

When I show any message dialogue like warning dialogue or help dialogue using Arabic text as the message it's not shown in a proper way.

**Examples**:

---

English:

```
helpdlg('Hello World !!');
```

[image: Hello world message]

---

Arabic:

```
helpdlg('أهلا أيها العالم');
```

[image: Ahlan message]

---

My thoughts goes to that it's character-encoding problem, I really don't know for sure !

I've tried to use different font like:

```
text(0.6,0.5,'أهلا و سهلا','fontname','david','rotation',180,'fontsize',50,'color','r');
text(0.6,0.5,'أهلا و سهلا','fontname','arial','rotation',180,'fontsize',50,'color','r');
text(0.6,0.5,'أهلا و سهلا','fontname','Arabic Typesetting','rotation',0,'fontsize',50,'color','r');
text(0.6,0.5,'أهلا و سهلا','fontname','Courier','rotation',0,'fontsize',50,'color','r');
```

And the problem still not solved.

**The question is,** How can Matlab dialogue messages appear in **Arabic** ?

Comment: I suspect that this is an issue with the MATLAB fonts. Did you try playing with the font preferences?

Comment: you might be interested in this http://www.sourcecodeonline.com/list?q=arabic_character_recognition_with_matlab

Comment: @Shai: I've tried the solution in this question but id doesn;t work,

`text(0.1,0.5,'لغة عربية','fontname','Courier','rotation',0.,'fontsize',50,'color','r')`

Comment: @Shai -Aliecum Al-Salam: I've tried many fonts including `Arabic Typesetting` that for sure support Arabic.

Comment: @Shai: question is edited.

Comment: @SamehKamal Is this problem exclusive to dialogs, or do you have similar problems with figures?

Comment: @slayton: no the problem is with any Arabic text in any form of display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to **change machine local numbers and formats to Arabic** [[Guide]](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307938)

then restart Matlab and Arabic will be supported in GUI, command window, Workspace and etc..

Only dialogues still don't support Arabic.

[image]